# Return to previous page in joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have created my own extension. This extension can be accessed from different components and parts of the website.

The problem I have is that there could be a number of different URLs that link to this extension. I have a 'cancel' button and I can't work out how I would get this button to link to the previous URL.

Wondering if there is something built into joomla like getPreviousURL? Couldn't find anything.

EDIT: I should have said that I still want to be able to run my cancel() method. e.g. index.php?option=com_mycomp&task=mycomp.cancel. The cancel() method will then perform a redirection to the previous page.

Comment: what do you mean by "previous url"? the previous url in browser history or something else?

Comment: Well, I don't really want to use the browsers history, but yes, I mean the URL that IF you clicked the back button, thats the URL you would go to.

Comment: then use "window.history.back();"

Comment: I'm not sure you've really understood the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question right, This will help you out for sure. Joomla does not support something like that but Javascript does.

JS

```
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="goBack()" />
```

> The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list. This is
>   the same as clicking the Back button or history.go(-1).

***Updated Answer as required.***

PHP

If JavaScript isn't a possibility, you could use the HTTP_REFERER, sanitize it, and echo it out via PHP.

```
<?php
  $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  $this->setRedirect($url);
?>
```

> This will not work if
>
> - entered the site URL in browser address bar itself.
> - visited the site by a browser-maintained bookmark.
> - visited the site as first page in the window/tab.
> - has security software installed (antivirus/firewall/etc) which strips    the referrer from all requests.
> - visited the site programmatically (like, curl) without setting the    referrer header (searchbots!).

If you come across any problems let me know.

Update answer - Joomla method

```
$url = JFactory::getURI();
$request_url = $url->toString();
```

Comment: Thanks Dasun. Sorry I should have said that I still want to be able to run my cancel() method. e.g. index.php?option=com_mycomp&task=mycomp.cancel. The cancel() method will then perform a redirection to the previous page.

Comment: thanks - that doesn't seem to work. It just refreshes the page i.e. its the same URL as the current page.

Comment: see whether you come across any of the above situations

Comment: Non of the above apply. htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) is outputting a URL, its just a modification of the current pages URL. I think it may be because joomla does some internal redirecting that may be messing it up

Comment: This Joomla method $request_url = $url->toString(); only shows the current page not the previous page

Answer (score 1):

I’ve done it this ways:

1. Install Joomla extension “jumi” @ url http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jumi
2. Create a html file(ex: back.html) and write following code:

```js
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()" />
```

3. Save it into Joomla root directory.
4. Create a custom module in Joomla and write syntax :

{jumi [back.html]}

5. Publish this module

I hope it’ll work.
thanks